# why ul-list items not getting space between them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a line in which the list item should have space in a row but I'm not getting why it is not applying when using `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between` is applied in ul-list class

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 650px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ul-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list-item {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="n1">
    <div>Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list1">
    <ul class="ul-list">
      <li class="list-item">ONE </li>
      <li class="list-item">TWO</li>
      <li class="list-item">THREE</li>
      <li class="list-item">FOUR</li>
      <li class="list-item">FIVE</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="n1">
    <div>RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this can be done by applying a margin, but why it's not getting why not with `space-around`?

Comment: There simply _is_ no extra space to distribute, because your UL is only as wide as the LI demand. (The space on the left, inside the green border, is the default `padding-left` the UL gets from the user agent stylesheet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between` will put space between your flex items **only if** the flex container is larger than the items.

In your case, you could set a width for `.ul-list` which is wider than the contents, or you can set a `gap` as suggested by @ImranMalik.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.ul-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid green;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list-item {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="n1">
        <div>Left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list1">
        <ul class="ul-list">
            <li class="list-item">ONE </li>
            <li class="list-item">TWO</li>
            <li class="list-item">THREE</li>
            <li class="list-item">FOUR</li>
            <li class="list-item">FIVE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="n1">
      <div>Right</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="n1">
        <div>Left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list1">
        <ul class="ul-list" style="width: 285px;">
            <li class="list-item">ONE </li>
            <li class="list-item">TWO</li>
            <li class="list-item">THREE</li>
            <li class="list-item">FOUR</li>
            <li class="list-item">FIVE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="n1">
      <div>Right</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="n1">
        <div>Left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list1">
        <ul class="ul-list" style="gap: 1em;">
            <li class="list-item">ONE </li>
            <li class="list-item">TWO</li>
            <li class="list-item">THREE</li>
            <li class="list-item">FOUR</li>
            <li class="list-item">FIVE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="n1">
      <div>Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.ul-list { gap: 10px; }`
Use `gap` property to add spaces between flex items.

Comment: to answer why it is not working with `space-between`is: The list is a flex-item and as such only as wide as the content. Space-between only applies the remaining space equally between all items. As said before, a flex-item is only as large as the content and as such there is no remaining space to apply equally.